# how to load the Jquery response(HTML page with script tags) into the DOM

Tags: jquery, append, response

test1.html file:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.js">
</script>
<script>

function loadfn(){

$.get('test.html',function(data){

alert($(data).text());
//$('body div#returnData').html(data);
$.each(data, function(i, node) { 
    alert(i);
   if (node.tagName == "SCRIPT") {
       eval(node.innerHTML); 

   } else {
       $(node).appendTo($('#returnData')); 
   }

});

});
test1();
test2();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="returnData" >
</div>
<input type="button" value="Click" onclick=loadfn()>
</body>
</html>
```

test.html :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js">
</script>
</head>
<script>
function test1(){
alert('test1 function');
}
</script>
<script>
function test2(){
alert('test2 function');
}
</script>
<body>
<div id="testdiv">
Text field : <input type="text" value="Test Value"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Actually i have the requirement that i have to load the test.html page into test1.html and then run the script functions that are there in that page.

The Above code snippet doesnt suffice the requirement. Please let me know what i am doing wrong in the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do something like this so that it loads script element , so my advise is when you  get response replace `script` string with `scri" + "pt`

```
var code = "<script>alert('Hi!');</scr"+"ipt>";
$('body').append($(code)[0]);
```

Comment: why script tag has to be splitted???whether only </script> is required to be split or both <script> and </script>

Comment: @Rajesh - to prevent the dom parser from thinking that the string '<script>' is in fact a dom tag

Comment: @PranayRana: Agreed. But he is not writing it inline. This is part of an ajax result, it seems.

Comment: @RobinMaben - but he can replace the script tag which comes in response by using replace() function....what say ?

Comment: @PranayRana:even the below code doesnt work out for me... $.get('test.html',function(data){
alert($(data).text());
var chdata = $(data).text().replace('/script/g','scri+pt');
alert(chdata);
$('body div#returnData').html(chdata);
test1();

});

Answer (score 0):

You need not "load" it into your DOM.
For script tags, you could just do..

```
eval("<script>alert('Hi!');</script>");
```

**UPDATE :**

If you result contains **both** HTML and SCRIPT nodes, do the following..

```
$.each(nodes, function(i, node) { //result might contain muliple HTML/Script nodes

   if (node.tagName == "SCRIPT") {
       eval(node.innerHTML); 
       //Appending to DOM also executes the script. So we do eval() instead, which does the equivalent.
   } else {
       $(node).appendTo($('#returnData')); //And append your HTML nodes to the desired target div
   }

});
```

Comment: But the response i will be getting will have both html tags and script tags. the above snippet have only script tags. whether in that case also it work ah?

Comment: :Can you elaborate the code and explain me how to use this for the code that have pasted above.I mean in the callback method i have to load the html contents into div #returnData and what will happen to the functions that are inside scripts. Whether the functions will be available for invoking in the jquery get request itself...Pls help me in clarifying..

Comment: :I have edited the question. Can u explain me . I am Still not able to solve my issues.

Comment: Can you explain me. I am still not able to fix it.

Comment: I am getting "Could not convert JavaScript argument" error in Firebug.