# Issue with jQuery AJAX - code runs on load, then nothing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

thanks for taking a look at my question!

This has been driving me nuts for hours. I'm trying to load and render a file into div on my page using jQuery AJAX. For some reason, any jQuery (or vanilla JS) is running when it's loaded, but any subsequent functions that should run on a click, don't run. HTML is rendered and updated in the DOM, but any script tags are not there.

I'm building a WordPress website on an existing installation, it can be viewed here: [www.reckless-intent.com](http://www.reckless-intent.com/?theme=ri2) My issue can be reproduced by clicking the Contact link in the left sidebar.

At the top of the content area, a div will appear with the content 'BUTTON' in it. When the content loads, there is a console loge triggered. There is a function bound to the button, and it should trigger another console log - but nothing happens!

Here is all the code behind it:

The following function starts with displaying a loading animation, then initiates an AJAX call to the get-contact.php file.

```
$('#loading').fadeIn('fast', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.reckless-intent.com/wp-content/themes/ri2/page-templates/get-contact.php",
        success: postToPage
    }); // close AJAX call
}); // close function
```

This next function then sets the content that was requested into a proxy div, calculates its height, animates the height of the main container 'stage' and then displays the requested content in the stage div.

```
function postToPage(data, status) {
$('#proxy').html(data);
    var height = $('#proxy').height();
    $('#drawer').fadeIn('fast');
    $('#drawer').animate({'height': '300'}, 100);
    $('#stage').html(data);
    $('#stage').fadeIn(300);
    $('#loading').fadeOut('fast');  
}
```

The get-contact.php file contains the following:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: get-contact
*/

require('../../../../wp-load.php'); ?>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log('Initial run');
    $('#test').on('click',test);
    function test() {
        console.log('button clicked');
    }
</script>

<div id="test">
    BUTTON
</div>
```

I really have no idea what's causing the issue. All of my calls are within the same domain, so I don't think there would be anything blocking the script from running that way.

Can you point me in the right direction? I won't change any of my code, if you need to view the code for yourself on the website.

I really appreciate your time! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DOM is not ready when you reference the #test button. Use event delegation methods to allow the event to bubble up the DOM - I injected the following js into the site and now clicks are registered:

```
$('body').on({click:function(){console.log('clicked');}}, '#test');
```

Comment: Wow - this worked! I've updated the code on the website with the above and the button on-click log is now being registered.

Comment: I know this sounds odd, but why does that happen? Even referencing .js files directly didn't work.

Comment: This is caused by the way event handlers work. A DOM element must be on the page when the on event is attached. When using dynamically injected elements you must use event delegation and reference a parent element that has not been dynamically injected first (in this case 'body'). This way the event bubbles up the DOM and finds the element that the event handler was bound to.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! Do you know why none of the <script> tags appear in the DOM after it's loaded? It led me to thinking that they were being stripped out or something.

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234014/how-to-load-the-jquery-responsehtml-page-with-script-tags-into-the-dom

Answer (score 3):

try wrapping the loaded javascript like this to wait for the html to be loaded

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
       console.log('Initial run');
       $('#test').on('click',test);
       function test() {
        console.log('button clicked');
       }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah, definitely looks like an issue where an element is referenced before the DOM is ready.

Comment: I see and understand that change, however it does not fix the issue. The initial run log runs perfectly fine, but when I click on the button div, there is no log.

Comment: Try moving the `function test()..` function before the `$(function(){` line